# xml traversal in python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have an xml file of the following form:

```
<Op Id="Op_Join" I="14">
    <Op Id="Op_Sort" I="1">                                                      
        <Op Id="Op_Join" I="2">
             <Op Id="Op_Exchange" I="11">                                                          
                   <Op Id="Op_Extract" I="5">                                                            
                   </Op>
             </Op>
        </Op>
    </Op>
</Op>
```

Now I want to traverse this xml file in a bottom-up manner. That is, starting from the bottom "Op_Extract". I want to find the first "Op_Join" that it comes across while traversing from bottom to top. In the example xml file above the first "Op_Join" has I="2".

I know I can use "xml.etree.ElementTree" in python to traverse the xml file in a top-down manner. However I am looking for a way to traverse the xml file in a bottom-up manner.

The xml document that I have can be arbitrarily complex. The snippet pasted here is just for exposition.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite traversing in reverse (although I don't see why that couldn't be possible), but for the problem described you can use `xpath` to get the nodes that match your criteria, it should order them according to how the document is laid out and should be able to grab the last one.

```
## parsing data.
In [18]: from lxml import etree

In [19]: x = """
    ...: <Op Id="Op_Join" I="14">
    ...:     <Op Id="Op_Sort" I="1">
    ...:         <Op Id="Op_Join" I="2">
    ...:              <Op Id="Op_Exchange" I="11">
    ...:                    <Op Id="Op_Extract" I="5">
    ...:                    </Op>
    ...:              </Op>
    ...:         </Op>
    ...:     </Op>
    ...: </Op>"""

### creating an lxml object using etree:

In [20]: x = etree.fromstring(x)

In [21]: [e.get('I') for e in x.xpath('//Op[@Id="Op_Join"]')][-1]
Out[21]: '2'
```